# paramiko ssh client does not work with HP switches

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I've been using my script for a unix server and it's working perfectly. However when i use the same script( with some minor command changes) to connect to HP Procurve switches , script crashes with error. Part of the script is below:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(address, username=userna, password=passwd)

stdin,stdout,stderr= ssh.exec_command("show ver")

for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')

ssh.close()
```

This gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kucar/Desktop/my_python/switchmodel", line 34, in <module>
stdin,stdout,stderr= ssh.exec_command("show ver")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 379, in exec_command
chan.exec_command(command)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 218, in exec_command
self._wait_for_event()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1122, in _wait_for_event
raise e
SSHException: Channel closed.
```

I've found similar complaints in the web however seems like solution is not provided at all. Switch is open to ssh and works fine with putty. Appreciate if you give any ideas that could help me. I cannot do "show ver" command manually for 100 switches.

Answer (score 3):

As @dobbo mentioned above you have to do invoke_shell() on the channel so that you can execute multiple commands. Also HP ProCurve has ANSI Escape Codes in the output so you have to strip those out. Finally, HP ProCurve throws up a "Press any key to continue" message which you have to get past at least on some devices.

I have an HP ProCurve handler in this library https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko

Set device_type to "hp_procurve".

Exscript also has some sort of a ProCurve handler though I haven't dug into it enough to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience connecting to my Samsung s4 phone with an ssh server.
I had no problem connecting to a SUSE VM or a Rasperry Pi and also tried MobaXterm (putty is SO last week).

I have not found the answer but will share my research.

I had a look at the source and found line 1122 in channel.py (copied below).

With my phone (and possibly your HP switch) I have noticed that there is no login message or MOTD at all and when exiting (with putty/mobaXterm) the session doesn't end properly.

In some other reading, I have found that the parameko is not getting much support from the author any more but others are working to port it to python 3x.

Here is the source code I found.

```
def _wait_for_send_window(self, size):
    """
    (You are already holding the lock.)
    Wait for the send window to open up, and allocate up to C{size} bytes
    for transmission.  If no space opens up before the timeout, a timeout
    exception is raised.  Returns the number of bytes available to send
    (may be less than requested).
    """
    # you are already holding the lock
    if self.closed or self.eof_sent:
        return 0
    if self.out_window_size == 0:
        # should we block?
        if self.timeout == 0.0:
            raise socket.timeout()
        # loop here in case we get woken up but a different thread has filled the buffer
        timeout = self.timeout
        while self.out_window_size == 0:
            if self.closed or self.eof_sent:
                return 0
            then = time.time()
            self.out_buffer_cv.wait(timeout)
            if timeout != None:
                timeout -= time.time() - then
                if timeout <= 0.0:
                    raise socket.timeout()
    # we have some window to squeeze into
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if you don't clean up the connection buffer Paramiko goes nuts when working with HP Procurves. First off you need to invoke a shell or Paramiko will simply drop the connection after the first command (normal behavior, but confusing).

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(switch_ip, username=switch_user, password=switch_pass,look_for_keys=False)
conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
recieveData() # <-- see below
```

It's important to actually handle the data, and as I've learned you need to make sure Paramiko has actually received all the data before you ask it to do stuff with it. I do this by using the following function. You can adjust the sleep as needed, in some cases 0.050 will work fine.

```
def recieveData():
    tCheck = 0
    while not conn.recv_ready():
        time.sleep(1)
        tCheck+=1
        if tCheck >=10:
            print "time out"
    cleanThatStuffUp(conn.recv(1024)) # <-- see below
```

This is an example of the garbage that is returning to your ssh client.

```
[1;24r[24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1HProCurve Switch 2650# [24;1H[24;23H[24;1H[?5h[24;23H[24;23Hconfigure[24;23H[?25h[24;32H[24;0HE[24;1H[24;32H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?5h[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1H
```

There's also exit codes to deal with before each "[". So to deal with that I figured out some regex to clean all of that "stuff" up.

```
procurve_re1 = re.compile(r'(\[\d+[HKJ])|(\[\?\d+[hl])|(\[\d+)|(\;\d+\w?)')
procurve_re2 = re.compile(r'([E]\b)')
procurve_re3 = re.compile(ur'[\u001B]+') #remove stupid escapes

def cleanThatStuffUp(message):
   message = procurve_re1.sub("", message)
   message = procurve_re2.sub("", message)
   message = procurve_re3.sub("", message)
   print message
```

Now you can go about entering commands, just make sure you clear out the buffer each time using recieveData().

```
conn.send("\n") # Get past "Press any key"
recieveData()
```